# How to draw a filled path built of arcs

Tags: gdi+

Might be a simple question:

how can I draw a filled graphic path built with lines and arcs? The problem is, that GDI+ defines an arc from starting angle to end angle with clockwize orientation only.

[Image to be made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT1Fq.png)

A sample (any language) would be great!

It should be made by setting the end point of an arc is the starting point of the next line and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way =>

- Result :

[image]

- Code (C#, VS 2015) :
  (drawing on screen DC for testing) :

```cs
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
   RectangleF rect = new Rectangle(500, 100, 400, 400 / 2);
   RectangleF rectArc;
   float nXradius = 60;
   float nYradius = 60;

   PointF point1, point2;
   GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

   // Upper Left
   rectArc = new RectangleF(rect.X, rect.Y, 2 * nXradius, 2 * nYradius);
   gp.AddArc(rectArc, 180, 90);
   point1 = new PointF(rect.X + nXradius, rect.Y);                   

   // Top Border                   
   point2 = new PointF(rect.Right - nXradius, rect.Y);                   
   gp.AddLine(point1, point2);

   // Upper Right.
   rectArc = new RectangleF(rect.Right - 2 * nXradius, rect.Y, 2 * nXradius, 2 * nYradius);
   gp.AddArc(rectArc, 270, 90);
   point1 = new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Y + nYradius);

   // Right Border
   point2 = new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom - nYradius);                   
   gp.AddLine(point1, point2);

   // Lower Right
   rectArc = new RectangleF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom - 2 * nYradius, 2 * nXradius, 2 * nYradius);
   gp.AddArc(rectArc, -180, -90);
   point1 = new PointF(rect.Right + nXradius, rect.Bottom);

   // Bottom Border                  
   point2 = new PointF(rect.X - nXradius, rect.Bottom);                  
   gp.AddLine(point1, point2);

   // Lower Left
   rectArc = new RectangleF(rect.X - 2 * nXradius, rect.Bottom - 2 * nYradius, 2 * nXradius, 2 * nYradius);
   gp.AddArc(rectArc, 90, -90);
   point1 = new PointF(rect.X, rect.Bottom - nYradius);                  

   // Left Border
   point2 = new PointF(rect.X, rect.Y + nYradius);                   
   gp.AddLine(point1, point2);

   gp.CloseFigure();
   System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 10);
   pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
   gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   gr.DrawPath(pen, gp);
   gr.FillPath(System.Drawing.Brushes.Orange, gp);
}
```